# Can i lose messages if I have more partitions than consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I'm reading messages from a kafka topic with 3 replicas and 70 partitions by using the storm-kafka api, the kafka spout that I'm using has 15 executors, is possible to lose messages because I don't have 70 executors ?

How can I ensure that all the messages in kafka were received by a consumer ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka has by default an at least once delivery guarantee for data that you already know made it to Kafka. If you have fewer consumer instances than partitions for a consumer group, then the consumers will be assigned multiple partitions according to your partition assignment strategy. By default it uses the RangeAssignor. You can read more about the delivery semantics for Kafka [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#semantics).